# Select value in combobox to sort items in Javascript

Tags: javascript, combobox, selection

is there a quick way to select value in combobox to sort items? Is there anything to add or edit or remove?

Please give me any idea.

```
<div id="sort-wrapper" class="sort-position">
     <div id="sort-container">
         Sort by: <select id="sort-item">
             <option value="Alphabetical";">Alphabetical</option>
             <option value="low to high">Low to High Price</option>
             <option value="high to low">High to Low Price</option>
         </select>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="content-position">
     <div id="content-container">
         <li>Corsair <label>2,000</label></li>
         <li>Cooler Master <label>3,000</label></li>
         <li>Antec <label>1,000</label></li>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually don't know if there's an easy way to do this or not.  I've seen examples with frameworks that make this behavior look easy.

However, this sounds interesting enough and if i were to do this in JS/jQuery, I'd:
1. have the select box mark up you provided,
2. store the results in an array of objects, 
3. read the selected value within the select box on change
4. sort the results by what's selected
5. update/append it to the DOM

Here's a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/pcesspxq/

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function(){   
  var arr = [], $opts = 1;

  arr.push({"name":"Corsair","price":"2000"});
  arr.push({"name":"Cooler Master","price":"3000"});
  arr.push({"name":"Antec","price":"1000"});

  $('#sort-item').change(function() { 
      $opts = $(this).find('option:selected')[0].dataset.sort; 
      updateContent(arr,$opts); 
  });

  updateContent(arr,$opts);            
});

function updateContent(arr,$opts) {
  var $result = $('#content-container');
  $result.text("");

  if ( $opts == 1 ){
      arr.sort( function(a,b) { return a.name > b.name; } );
  }
  else if ($opts == 2) {
      arr.sort( function(a,b) { return a.price - b.price; } );
  }
  else if ($opts == 3) {
      arr.sort( function(a,b) { return b.price - a.price; } );
  }

  for (var i =0; i< arr.length; i++) {         
    $result
      .append('<li>'+arr[i].name+" $"+arr[i].price+'</li>');
  }
}
```